# Usage of "more than" before a verb

Tags: meaning, verbs, adverbs

In the Longman dictionary, there is an example for *Compensate* as follows:

> Her intelligence **more than compensates** for her lack of experience.

I am wondering what the grammatical point of using **more than** before a verb is here. How does it modify the meaning of verb? Could somebody give another example of such usage?

***Update:*** Does the following sentence have the same meaning?

> Her intelligence compensates for her lack of experience **more than needed/required**.

Comment: In general, action taken to *compensate for* something implies *exactly counterbalances*. So to *more than compensate* means the rebalancing action actually goes further than necessary to equalise the situation. In this specific context, it simply means her intelligence is so high (or highly valued) as a positive attribute that this actually *outweighs* her negative attribute (lack of experience). Making her "net worth" positive, rather than simply neutral.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's simply used as an intensifier to indicate that more was done than just the bare action.

> Her intelligence compensates for her lack of experience.

This means that her intelligence makes her equivalent to someone who has adequate experience.

> Her intelligence more than compensates for her lack of experience.

This means that her intelligence makes her better than someone who has adequate experience.

A separate example:

> He cleared the high jump bar with his leap.

This means that he exceeded the height of the bar

> He more than cleared the high jump bar with his leap.

This means that he jumped higher than just the height of the bar, probably by a large margin.

**Update**

Yes, that would be a correct interpretation of the sentence.

Comment: Your update is not correct. The answer is a no to the question about 'more than needed/required.'. Need or requirement is a completely different criterion and is not relevant here.

Comment: I accepted your answer. But with respect to @Kris, I doubt your answer to my updated question.